# WPF Radiobutton loses state after scrolling in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scroll, virtualization

I have a wpf app that has a datagrid that is filled with questions.  Each question has two groups of radiobuttons (good, better, best; and unimportant, important, most important).  There are roughly 200 questions that get populated into the grid with about 15-20 showing without needing to scroll.  I've got the logic down to allow for selection of the radiobuttons, but when I scroll I the objects loose their focus and don't keep the the answers.

Basically, I can answer the first 20 questions but when I scroll down then I lose the answers due to the virtualization of the datagrid.  I tried turning it off but then the app takes forever to load and sorting goes out the window.  I have to keep it turned on.  Anyone know how to keep the state of the radiobuttons after scrolling?

Answer (score 2):

RadioButtons is forbidden to use with virtualization. Try to use StackPanel :

```
<DataGrid x:Name = "MyDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}">
 <DataGrid.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
   <StackPanel/>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
 </DataGrid.ItemsPanel>
 <DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
     <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
      <RadioButton Content="Yes" IsChecked="{Binding Checked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"/>
      <RadioButton Content="No" IsChecked="{Binding Checked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource BoolInverterConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
     </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn>
 </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that the RadioButtons outside of the initial view turned out to be unresponsive when I scrolled that into view.
A refresh of the data while the DataGrid was scrolled there made them responsive again. But that was not acceptable.

The solution was what I noticed here about Virtualization. In some stylesheet it was generally set on. By setting EnableRowVirtualization="False" on my specific DataGrid I got rid of the problem. Loading did seem to get slower.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was facing the same problem and your comment helped me to solve it :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you didn't bind the state of your radio buttons to the related view model. As a consequence this state wouldn't be saved and got lost, when the UI refreshes. Try applying a two-way-binding.

Comment: So I checked that and ran it in debug mode to see what was going on.  It does have two-way binding turned on and is bound to the view-model.  What happens is when the UI unloads the rows (when they are no longer on the screen) it triggers the propertychanged and sets everything to false. I'm not sure why it sets everything to false though.

Comment: How did you bind the value of your radio buttons to your view model, perhaps there's an error. Would be great, if you could edit your question and add the related code, to find the error faster.